# Efficiency of product of scalar by a sum

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

> [image]

I have written this code for calculating the n-partial sum $\mathrm{S_n}$ of a given series, but would it be more numerical efficient to write 6*sum(...)? If so, why?

Comment: A more concerning problem are the `n^2/2` calls to `term` instead of the actually needed `n` ones. `n` additional multiplications are negligible against the multiplications in the term expression.

Comment: But without concerning the calls to 'term', which approach would be more efficient: multiplying each summand or multiplying the final sum?

Comment: Obviously the variant with less operations is more efficient. The result should be largely the same, the floating-point errors might fall different for the different orders of operation, but that is not relevant for small to medium large `n`.